# Serilog does not see configuration updates if the configuration is changed programmatically

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, serilog

This is what my Serilog configuration code looks like. reloadOnChange is true. If I manually change the serilog.json file with the Serilog configuration, everything works. But if I change the serilog.json configuration file programmatically, nothing works and it's like Serilog doesn't see the changes.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTS4l.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ACgyv.png)

I am trying to update the configuration programmatically but Serilog does not see these changes

Comment: Try adding reader.Flush(); before the reader.Close();  The file may be small and closing isn't saving results.

Comment: Far more people will read your question if you post the code as text, not images (that need to be clicked through on). And thats before you consider people using screen readers